# Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

In the sentence

> What’s funny is Cat’s dry humour.

Wouldn’t it be better to put a comma after “funny”:

> What’s funny, is Cat’s dry humour.

This question entails a (at the time of writing) heated discussion in the [SO chat C++ lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).

Comment: "Heated" is overstating a bit, but yeah.  It's worth knowing the answer at least.  (I already know, but let's get an official word. :) )

Comment: The difference between a cat and a comma: a cat has claws at the end of its paws, and a comma is a pause at the end of a clause.

Comment: @JLG: I can't help that Brits have a glut of "U"s and have to get rid of them somehow.  Somewhere there's poor children that can't read cause there aren't enough "U"s.  Stop the waste, Brits!  *Think of the children!*  :)

Comment: The comma is spurious.  This isn’t German.

Comment: Ah, the old "verb comma verb". I remember it well...

Comment: @AndrewLeach I must regularly extirpate spurious commas from Commonwealth writers’ works I edit.  Quite annoying, really.  What do you think, is the source of all this nonsense?

Comment: As far as the UK is concerned, I think, it's a laxity in education about the rudiments of grammar. For quite some time, content and expressing ideas were king and the frilly bits like commas didn't matter. Unfortunately, grammar is necessary in order to express content clearly :-(

Comment: @cHao: I suppose we might give some of our U's to you Americans. You don't seem to have enough... :-)

Comment: @tchrist Well, German punctuation has clear rules for commas and “insert a pause” ain’t one of them.

Comment: @cHao 'With that said, though, there are a number of dictionaries (like the Oxford English Dictionary), ...  that many people consider at least semi-authoritative. They tend to be highly influential as far as business and formal English go, to the point where professors, editors, etc will often consider your speech/writing "incorrect" if it didn't adhere to a certain style guide's rules or had words pronounced/spelled in ways that aren't listed in a certain dictionary.' (from a recent answer you give). OED licences 'humour'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: And what does the rest of that answer say?  "It's basically a controlled anarchy."  But i have to laugh a bit about the quote mining over what is very obviously a joke. Thanks for that :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Maybe you should go as far as to read my other comment under this very post before spouting off about ignorance and elitism.

Comment: @CHao I did. It came across as an attempt at a face-saver. Make sure of your facts before telling others they're wrong ('Oh, and you misspelled "humor" '). And your 'It's worth knowing the answer at least. (I already know ...' looks lightweight. Now included is a reference to an authority licensing a comma between subject and verb under certain conditions; it's the only authority actually dealing with the question which is referenced here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Dude. Take your cross elsewhere.  It was clearly a joke. That you don't get it says more about you than me.

Comment: @CHao While we're discussing contributions that might be unhelpful to readers, your intransitive usage of _overstate_ ("Heated" is overstating a bit, ...) is not licensed by any online dictionary I've checked in. How are people to know when you should be taken seriously?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Simple. If i am stating what i believe to be a fact, i do not just immediately back off or attempt to joke it away. As for my grammar, you know quite well that "authorities" are anything but, and since you felt the need to root around in my history, you know i hold the same view. So why are you going full pedant over jokes from over two and a half years ago? You really think you're adding something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it would not be better.

The reason is that it's a single clause, with "What's funny" as the subject of the verb ("is") and "Cat's dry humour" as the complement.

Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma.

Answer (score 9):

A comma isn't necessary there.

"*What's funny*" is a noun clause. It's similar to, for instance, "*what you need*."

> A loan is what you need.

So:

> Cat's dry humor is what's funny.

It's the same thing inverted:

> What's funny is Cat's dry humor.

Answer (score 6):

It was standard for much of Modern English history to use a comma to separate a complex subject (“What’s funny…”) from the rest of the sentence (“…is Cat’s dry humour”). This is in line with the purpose of punctuation in general—to indicate [prosody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosody_(linguistics)). Many speakers actually *do* pause at that point in a sentence, so a comma seems only natural.

In the passages below, [,] denotes a comma which is present in the original text, but is widely (albeit arbitrarily) considered incorrect in contemporary English.

> Treason against the United States[,] shall consist only in levying War against them, or in adhering to their Enemies, giving them Aid and Comfort.
>
> A well regulated Militia[,] being necessary to the security of a free State, the right of the people to keep and bear Arms[,] shall not be infringed.

In short: it’s best avoided unless you’re intentionally writing in the style of the early 1800s.

Answer (score 2):

[The New Oxford Guide to Writing By Thomas S. Kane {1988}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-AL43YC_cZsC&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=%22comma+between+the+subject+and+the+verb%22&source=bl&ots=9I1vO0WSWS&sig=j-JNV9ehu_c5gBE_byU2P7nO5Vg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0P8nVf6GEM_daL_tgeAG&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22comma%20between%20the%20subject%20and%20the%20verb%22&f=false) doesn't accept the mantra 'Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma' as being an inviolable edict:

> The main elements of a sentence – the subject, verb and object – are
>   not separated by commas **except under unusual conditions** [bolding
>   mine]. Very occasionally when the subject is not a single word but a
>   long construction, such as a [lengthy] noun clause, a comma may be put
>   in at its end to signal the verb [ie make the reading easier]:
>
> *What makes the generation of the '60s different, is that it is largely inner-directed and uncontrolled by adult-doyens.* [Time
>   Magazine]
>
> In such a sentence the comma between the subject and the verb may help
>   readers to follow the grammar.

Comment: +1 not (just) for the quote, but for common sense and a bit of antiprescriptivism. IOW never say never

Comment: On the other hand, that comma makes no sense for me; it doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Andrew Leach Perhaps [this example from GrammarMonster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_a_long_subject.htm): << Leaving a list of Internet passwords, increasing your life insurance and writing a will, will give you peace of mind while you are on operations. 
(We judge the comma in this example to be helpful.) >>?

Comment: No, not for me. If there were an *and* before "increasing" in order to make that a parenthetical insertion, then Yes. But the list is the subject, and the comma grates horribly.

Comment: Whereas 'Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma.' puts my hackles up, as a (very good) rule of thumb presciptivised to rule status.