# Illegal Comma to Enhance Clarity

Tags: punctuation, commas

Consider such a concise law or rule: *AviD's Rule of Usability* [§§](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6116/33):

> **Security at the expense of usability, comes at the expense of security.**

It uses the comma splice. Someone suggested that  [§§](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase/6116#comment130012_6116):

> [...] either there should additionally be a comma after the first word or, as I prefer it, there should be no commas in it at all. I think you intended the comma to indicate a pause, which is grammatically incorrect. **In this case, try an en dash (with spaces), an em dash (without spaces), or an ellipsis (with or without spaces).**

However, any kind of dash breaks up the sentence too much, an ellipsis is just out of place here, and adding a comma at the beginning (after "Security,") would drastically change the meaning of the statement. Also, removing the comma altogether just leaves it as more confusing and harder to parse.

From an unscientific poll of some of the other English readers (in Sec.SE), it seems almost everyone agrees that *in this case* it is better off leaving the single orphan comma.  ([Someone even said that it is legitimate grammar in 18th century..](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is/76884#76884))

**But the more I think about it, it seems to be hindering clarity** (at least for *that* user) **, does it?** .

So, how should the concise law or rule best be formulated?

Does using a comma really hinders readability (parsability) for a significant amount of 21st century English readers?

Comment: P.S. I would also be open to hear if anybody has a suggestion for a better name... ;-)

Comment: I think you're simply mistaken in thinking that adding a manifestly ungrammatical comma improves "clarity". If anything, it gets in the way of natural parsing, forcing the reader to wonder why that comma is there (pointlessly, since there is no truly rational justification).

Comment: This is not an easy sentence. I assume it means (Security at the expense of usability) comes at the expense of security. [brackets used to group as in maths] Since the sentence is so outlandish, adding a comma is a minor concern _providing it has benefit_ (especially clarification). I disagree with FF that this is not the case here. Using brackets as I've done makes things even clearer to those who understand the maths usage. I'd be tempted to use them, even elsewhere (than in this post). Rephrasing would lose punch.

Comment: No matter who tells you the comma has to be there for good grammar, you should remove it to aid clarity.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth, that's exactly the intent. In fact in my head the comma serves the purpose of pseudo-brackets ;-)

Comment: @JonHanna the issue is exactly the opposite - the rules say to remove the comma, I put it IN to aid clarity. See e.g. Edwin's comment above yours.

Comment: Btw as @EdwinAshworth notes the sentence is purposely outlandish, precisely to force one to grapple with it intellectually, since the meaning is itself not trivial. Literary license, so to speak. I do accept that it is kinda technical-ish, and targeted at technical people. Don't know if that matters...

Comment: You put it in to aid clarity? How's that working out?

Comment: I've decided how I'd write it at last. "Security at the expense of usability . . . comes at the expense of security." Though _whether_ I'd write it is a different matter. Is it supposed to mean 'Prioritising usability of a product over security features actually backfires'?

Comment: There's a quote from *Catcher in the Rye* that similarly "misuses" a comma to aid clarity; I think he says "it was pretty funny, in a way". I think it's completely reasonable to use a comma to simulate the natural cadence of speech, even where the rules of grammar "forbid" it. I, unlike some commenters, believe that this comma *does* make the sentence more readable, as intended.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom; how is that similar?

Comment: @JonHanna it's an illegal comma that enhances the sentence by forcing you to think of it as the author would speak it.

Comment: @JonHanna well, over 500 people that read it understood it well enough, and the scores of people in the audience of the numerous talks I've given at conferences responded well to it too (though admittedly that was first said aloud, then appeared in writing...). One person raised the issue, half a dozen disagreed, and then I brought it here... So, overall, I would say "working out pretty well, until I go looking for issues..." ;-)

Comment: The rules of "grammar" have nothing to do with punctuation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I find the ellipsis to be unnatural there, and makes it seem that something is missing or withheld. It's meaning is as you cited originally: "(Security at the expense of usability) comes at the expense of security." I.e. prioritizing *security* at the expense of usability, eventually winds up coming at the cost of *lowered* security, not better (which is the counter-intuitive part).

Comment: P.S. Voting to close a question asking for advice on clarity, due to it being "unclear", is a bit ironic... No?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, 'ellipses can also indicate an unfinished thought, a leading statement, **a slight pause**, or a nervous or awkward silence' [bolding mine]. P.S. a question asking for advice on clarity, 'when the sentence is purposely outlandish, precisely to force one to grapple with it intellectually', is a lot ironic... No? [And note your use of the pause-for-thought ellipsis. What's that word in the back of my mind ...?]

Comment: I'd vote to play it straight up, with no internal punctuation. Part of the point of the statement (is it not?) is to startle the reader with the unexpected bump at the end, so why slow things down midway through? It's all decipherable with a little thought on the reader's part—certainly more so than Gertrude Stein's line (from "Sacred Emily"), "What is a winter wedding a winter wedding." Which in its own way is decipherable, too. Just my half a nickel rounded to the nearest even number of cents.

Comment: I've just read the original, from the link OP gives. It makes a lot of sense (probably with various choices of punctuation) if read after the preceding discussion. It's a good, punchy summary. But unless one accesses the original, referring to people largely giving up on security if it becomes too much of a hassle, (which OP should have provided here), it's far from easy to understand in any depth. **Clarity at the expense of giving extended context . . . comes at the cost of clarity.**

Comment: So, what we have found so far is that people outside the security industry definitely don't understand the meaning, insisting on removing the comma to lead to the opposite of what you intend. Which leads me to believe even more strongly that the comma is required - to force the mental effort required to parse it correctly. Leave it @AviD - I have quoted it to audiences and it works here in the UK.

Comment: Although I am one of the "you don't need a comma" people outside the security industry, I feel sure that I have understood the point of the quotation all along: Security measures that significantly interfere with system usability lead users to adopt informal avoidance countermeasures that ultimately negate the usefulness of the original security measures. In my view the comma after _usability_ isn't so much "illegal" as "superfluous." But at least adding it isn't as annoying as saying "Security at the expense of usability comes (wait for it) at the expense of security." So thumbs up for that.

Comment: @SvenYargs I think you just found a better way to rephrase it! I am SO adopting the (wait for it)... ;-) Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The version with a comma risks displeasing not only grammar Nazis but also the average reader. Because that comma splice is blatant.

The sentence without the comma

> Security at the expense of usability comes at the expense of security.

is confusing and may require several readings.

If you don't like the em dash, you could write the sentence with a relative clause or rewrite it, maybe starting it with *usability*.

Appealing to 18th century usage works--in the 18th century.

Comment: What makes this sentence confusing has nothing to do with the punctuation.  Cleverness, at the expense of clarity, comes at the expense of cleverness.

Comment: well put, TRomano!  .................And to AvID I say, the original should say "Security achieved at the expense of usability is useless (or unusable) security."  At least that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mind the comma, and I think I see why you wanted to phrase this as such, but it really isn't clear enough to become a "rule of thumb" - if that's what, in fact, you were shooting for. You could clarify it by simply saying:

"Compromising security with usability leads to compromised security."

Comment: Except that is the opposite of the intended meaning - Perhaps the first part would be "Compromising usability by security...". Also, it is precisely the surprising clarity, once parsed, and the non-intuitiveness ("the twist ending") that actually DID make it become a popular rule of thumb, quoted by others. Similar to saying "Unusable security isn't." (just not as overtly confusing as that one).

Comment: Oh... guess I misunderstood. So, I guess the lesson here is: you probably did need the comma, and don't clear a space for your "World's Greatest Rule of Thumb" trophy, yet. (Ben Franklin you ain't.)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that your use of the comma is sufficiently controversial that it distracts from getting your basic point across. Why not simply say:

> Security at the expense of usability is self-defeating

or

> Security at the expense of usability is counterproductive.

In my opinion, the following is clearer still:

> Security measures that are difficult to implement tend to lead to decreased security.

Unfortunately, when it is reanalysed in this way in order to make its meaning absolutely explicit, I think your original aphorism is revealed as being rather trite and obvious.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not obvious :-(

Comment: Also its not just a question of difficult to implement, or counterproductive in general, but the finer point is that it directly harms the cause it is purposely trying to achieve.

Comment: Persuasion at the expense of catchy phrasing comes at the expense of persuasion.