# Comma before "include:" preceding list: right or wrong, and why?

Tags: punctuation, commas

My first style disagreement with another writer at a new job. I say the comma in the example below is superfluous because there is no introductory or non-restrictive clause. I think the options are:
"Key takeaways from the press release include:"
or
"There are many key takeaways from the press release, including:"

Context: This was included in an email to our marketing team announcing the distribution of a press release, so if any of us get questions we'll all have the same answer.

As written:

> Key takeaways from the press release, include:
>
> This thing digitizes stuff and simplifies workflows.
> This thing changes how we see stuff, and makes customers happy.
> This thing improves the integrity of our stuff.
> This thing helps people see how stuff is being used.

Comment: We have a question on [Separating the subject from its verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is).

Comment: I don't understand how there could possibly be debate over this: that comma is wrong, wrong, wrong, wrong, wrong. Anyone who thinks otherwise has no business calling themselves a writer.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't think that's a duplicate: "what is funny, is" has two verbs, and the comma is thus arguable. "Key takeaways include" only has the one verb, and thus there is absolutely no way for the comma to be correct.

Comment: @Marthaª It's a duplicate because "What's funny" is the subject of the main verb (which happens to be *is* again).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, but the point is, "what's funny is" contains TWO (2) verbs. "Key takeaways include" has only ONE (1) verb. In my mind, this makes them pretty fundamentally different. In particular, I think a comma in "what's funny, is" is excusable: not the way I'd write it, but I can understand why someone would put it there. The comma before "include", on the other hand, is completely and totally WRONG.

Comment: I've added an authority sanctioning the use of a comma between [a lengthy] subject and verb (and an example from a well-regarded periodical) to the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely **no comma** in that clause, and I like your suggestions, esp the 1st.

Reason: **no comma between subject and verb**. Right, everyone? :-)

> [**Grammar by Diagram **](https://books.google.ca/books?id=l313UFxJbhcC&pg=PA265&dq=%22no%20comma%20between%20subject%20and%20verb%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xOgnVdCGEqG_sQSwxYCQCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22no%20comma%20between%20subject%20and%20verb%22&f=false) - Page 265 Cindy Vitto - 2008  ...
>
> INCORRECT: Whoever has parked in front of the
>   driveway, must move immediately. (comma between subject and verb)

**no-no**: *Key takeaways, include*

Comment: While I'd agree that one should label this particular comma-usage outlandish to unacceptable, the [New Oxford Guide to Writing By Thomas S. Kane {1988}](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-AL43YC_cZsC&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=%22comma+between+the+subject+and+the+verb%22&source=bl&ots=9I1vO0WSWS&sig=j-JNV9ehu_c5gBE_byU2P7nO5Vg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0P8nVf6GEM_daL_tgeAG&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22comma%20between%20the%20subject%20and%20the%20verb%22&f=false) doesn't accept the mantra 'Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma' as being an inviolable edict.

Comment: I'm wondering whether I'm less likely to push the boat out with 'outlandish' or 'unacceptable' usages....