# Is the comma before the verb "completed" used properly? The excerpt from Barron's SAT Practice Test - Test 3.?

Tags: commas

In an excerpt from Barron's SAT Practice Test - Test 3.

> A tiny pestle and mortar for color-grinding, and a cup of water in which to clip and wash the brush, completed the apparatus of the student.

I know that you cannot separate the subject from its verb. I wonder why there is a comma before the verb "completed". Doesn't it separate the verb from its subject *A tiny pestle and mortar for color-grinding, and a cup of water in which to clip and wash the brush,* where we are given a list of items in the following form: A and B, and C?

Comment: The sample sentence does not seem to be grammatical. "...apparatus if the student" is my primary suspect.

Comment: First correct the typo to _apparatus of the student_ or _for the student_. Then look at the sentence as A&B, with C along for the ride, rather than A-B-C. Two commas form the classic parenthetical expression.

Comment: The [compound] subject is certainly _A tiny pestle and mortar for color-grinding, and a cup of water in which to clip and wash the brush_. // With lengthy compound subjects, the rule 'no comma between subject and verb' becomes more flexible in the eyes of many. See the answer including "The New Oxford Guide to Writing By Thomas S. Kane {1988} doesn't accept the mantra 'Never separate the subject from its verb with a comma' as being an inviolable edict" at the duplicate.

Comment: Do the answers at the following thread answer your question? [Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is)

Comment: @Yosef Baskin A compound subject, not subject + parenthetical, here. [A and B] are / do / complete ....

Comment: @Edwin, I esteem your contributions. Here, I read the two commas as bracketing a secondary subject such as _along with a cup of water_. I don't see the cup as apparatus, but a trivial thing the student needs. Not being argumentative.

Comment: Civilised argument is essential for progress (assuming we're not all perfect). But what verb does your postulated second subject govern?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, Thanks for the guidance. It seems the most reasonable response. Checked the textbook, now things make sense.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin, if I treated C as the parenthetical information, wouldn't <,and> imply that there is another simple sentence coming further?