# is comma needed before the end clause

Tags: punctuation, commas, end-punctuation

I would like to know if in the following sentence the last comma (before 'will inevitably') is necessary.

- Actions such as cheating, manipulating, bad-mouthing, will inevitably bring adverse consequences on the perpetrator.

The above is just one example. I actually want to know whether, in a sentence similar to the above, it is necessary to put a comma after the last item in the list to separate the list from the end part of the sentence.

Thanks

Comment: You need an 'and' before _bad-mouthing_. I'd keep the comma after 'manipulating' though some might prefer otherwise. The comma after _bad-mouthing_, even though some might pause there when reading the sentence aloud, is non-standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wouldn't put a comma there, Edwin. I can't see what purpose it serves. There would be no suggestion of a comma in "Actions such as bad-mouthing will inevitably bring adverse consequences" so why is it necessary after the short list? However I would put commas around "inevitably" because it's parenthetical.

Comment: @BoldBen 'There'? Have you read the comment correctly? It's the Oxford comma after 'manipulating'.  Here, optional. // Zero punctuation round some parentheticals is quite acceptable, and I certainly prefer declutter here. In fact, it's a fine example; I'll add it to my small collection. // For instance, contrast 'The man’s wife died, sadly, and he inherited millions' and 'The man’s wife sadly died, and he inherited millions.'  I'd say the punctuation here is mandated, and 'sadly' is the same 'sentence adverb' in each variant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry I mis--read your comment, I was thinking of the comma _after_ 'bad-mouthing'. As you implied I didn't read read the test paper properly. Oops.