# Can a comma be used at the end of a restrictive clause to separate two verbs?

Tags: commas

Can/Should a comma be used at the end of a restrictive clause to separate two verbs (e.g. for clarity)?

- Everything that reduces the representative quality as copies of data are made, can be regarded as a form of “generation loss.”

I know that if the above sentence were simplified, as below, no comma would be necessary.

Everything that reduces the representative quality can be regarded as a form of “generation loss.”

All help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you shouldn't have a comma there. Why do you think you *might* want it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a comma necessary in "What’s funny, is …"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76850/is-a-comma-necessary-in-what-s-funny-is) @John Purdy's wise answer contains 'It was standard for much of Modern English history to use a comma to separate a complex subject (eg “What’s funny…”) from the rest of the sentence' but concludes: 'In short: it’s best avoided unless you’re intentionally writing in the style of the early 1800s.' // With some really convoluted subjects, omitting a comma _can_ lead one up garden paths or worse....

Comment: But then the preferred option is to rephrase. << We can regard as a form of 'generation loss' everything that reduces the representative quality as copies of data are made. >>

Comment: No: it's a basic rule of English grammar that a verb should not be separated from its subject.

Comment: @BillJ No punctuation rules are rules of English grammar, though!

Comment: @FumbleFingers A good reason might be because commas usually indicate a new Intonational Phrase (new musical tune). When a subject ends in a long relative clause, even a "restrictive one", the end of the relative clause normally ends with a nuclear tone and then a new IP begins beginning with the verb. So a writer's normal intuitive reaction to put a comma between two IPs is fubarred in this instance.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, Phil. Good question!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: You make a good point. The business about "a verb should not be separated from its subject" doesn't seem "bulletproof" to me - given that Shakespeare's [*Why then the world, and all that's in it, is nothing*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Why+then+the+world+and+all+that%27s+in+it+is+nothing%22) actually looks better to me *with* those commas than without. But "optional comma before a new Intonational Phrase" seems to cover things pretty well as a good "rule of thumb".